# How do I sort a MongoDB collection in MeteorJS permanently?

Tags: mongodb, sorting, meteor

From the tutorials out there I know that I can sort a MongoDB collection in meteor on request like this:

```
// Sorted by createdAt descending
Users.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}})
```

But I feel like this solution is not optimal in the view of performance.
Because if I understand it right, every time there is a request for `Users`, the raw collection is requested and then sorted over and over again.

So wouldn't it be better to sort the whole collection once and for all and then access the already sorted collection with `Users.find()`?

The question is: How do I sort the whole collection permanently not just the found results?

Comment: *"sort the whole collection"* doesn't really make sense in MongoDB which, per its documentation, doesn't guarantee *any* sort order on retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known limitation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6216) of MiniMongo, Meteor's client-side implementation of (a subset of) the MongoDB functionality.

"Sorting" a MongoDB *collection* does not really have a coherent meaning. It does not translate into a concrete set of operations. What would you sort it by? Is there a "natural" way to sort a set of documents which structure may vary?

The mechanism that is used for making data retrieval more efficient is an **index**. On the server, indices are used to assist sorting, if possible:

> In MongoDB, sort operations can obtain the sort order by retrieving documents based on the ordering in an index. If the query planner cannot obtain the sort order from an index, it will sort the results in memory. Sort operations that use an index often have better performance than those that do not use an index. In addition, sort operations that do not use an index will abort when they use 32 megabytes of memory.
>
> (Source: [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/))

As a collection does not have an inherent order to it, the entity that holds information about the order requirements in MongoDB is a Cursor. A cursor can be fetched multiple times, and in theory could be made into an efficient ordered data fetcher.

Unfortunately, this is not the case at the moment. The way it is currently implemented, MiniMongo does not have indices and does not cache the documents by order. They are re-sorted every time the cursor is fetched.

The sorting is reasonably efficient (as much as sorting can be efficient, `O(n*logn)` sort function invocations), but for a large data set, it could be fairly lengthy and degrade the user experience.

At the moment, if you have a special use case that requires repeated access to a large data-set that is ordered the same way, you could try to keep a cache of ordered documents if you need to, by observing the cursor and updating the cache when there are changes.